# No static files from the wwwroot folder after dockerize .net core mvc application on Rasperry Pi

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, raspberry-pi

I'm new in docker and I have a problem I can't deal with. I created .net core MVC application and this app is supposed to work on raspberry pi, so I dockerized my app on raspberry on HypriotOS and everything is good, but some images from wwwroot (default static files folder) is not Found (404). In wwwroot folder I have some css, js and images files and css, js and few images are available, but few .png files no. I don't have idea why.

- .net core version is 2.2
- I tired add line VOLUME ["/wwwroot"] in my Dockerfile
- in Startup.Configure() method I have line app.UseStaticFiles();

My Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestApp.dll"]
```

Commands to build and run Docker image:

```
docker build -t testapp .
docker run  -p 8080:80 --name testapp testapp
```

Dockerize passes correctly, no errors. The application is accessible from the outside, everything works, but some graphics are not displayed (404 Not Found).

Comment: did the directory containing static files get copied into the image?

Comment: How to check it?

Comment: you can log into the container bash and then `ls...`. 

To bash into container: `docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash`

Comment: Thanks, so into image I have only few static files (I don't have all .png files). So why  the created image don't have all files ? Should I add them manually?

Comment: when you are creating the image with your dockerfile, in line `COPY . ./` you are copying every resource from your host into the image. I guess there is where you are copying directory `wwwroot` right? At that very moment, that directory must contain everything you will need inside. With `docker cp` you can copy directly from your host to a running container, but new created containers out of the initial image won't contain then those files. If everything is solved let me know so we can create an "official" answer to your question for everyone with a similar issue :)

Comment: I copy all icons files manually using command `docker cp wwwroot/icons testapp:/app/wwwroot` and now is good. But why this all flies no included when I build docker image?

Comment: at the very moment of building the image, did this directory contain those images you were missing?

Comment: Yes, of course. All this images from wwwroot/icons directory are all the time in this directory. I have there 20 images, and when I build docker images, only 3 of these icons are copied. Every time , the same 3.

Answer (score 1):

Check your .dockerignore file for anything that might match the missing files/path.  That's what fixed this for me.